# chai-sorted with complex object

Tags: typescript, chai

I am using chai-sorted for my testing.
I need to test whether are array is correctly sorted against  an attribute

```
user.firstname
```

my chai-sorted instruction is

```
response.should.be.sortedBy('user.firstname');
```

But chai  is in error

```
AssertionError: expected '[null,null,null,null,null,null]' to be sorted in ascending order
at Object.<anonymous> (build/test/e2e/http/applicants-api.js:591:38)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (build/test/e2e/http/applicants-api.js:4:58)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

How can i specify  the sort on a attribute at the second level ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible because `chai-sorted` gets keys from items like this: `item[key]` so in your example it is `item['user.firstname']` which will not work. You could do it like this:

```
response.map(r => r.user).should.by.sortedBy('firstname')
```

It is of course not as nice as you way.